# How to preserve hyperlink when submitting via php form into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, hyperlink

I've created a form that stores free text fields into a MySQL database.

All works fine and the data is displayed back as intended when viewed. Except for one niggle.

In an attempt to prevent malicious attacks I have used mysql_real_escape_string to remove any unwanted code from the input.

However, I need to be able to preserve hyperlinks and basic html.

For example, I want to store the following:

`<p align="left">Please follow this <a href="link.html">link</a></p>`

But the link is being stored as \"link.html\" as the quotes are being escaped.

How can I preserve this link and other html?

Many thank

TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP function [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the escaping slashes from the quotes:

```
echo stripslashes($textos);
```

Comment: This did the trick. Knew it would be simple. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whilst that works, the *real* solution is to turn off magice_quotes_gpc in your php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you quote string twice. Did you turn off [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

That's not mysql_real_escape_string() doing that - I suspect it's actually [magic quotes](http://us.php.net/magic_quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP5, the best way is to use prepared statements with the PDO extension - this handles everything for you.